# Arduino - Nibble to Integer function erratic results

Tags: c++, arduino

I have the below code, that gives erratic results.

```
int nibbleToInt(String val) {
  int result;

  if(val.substring(3,4) == "1") { result += 1; }
  if(val.substring(2,3) == "1") { result += 2; }
  if(val.substring(1,2) == "1") { result += 4; }
  if(val.substring(0,1) == "1") { result += 8; }

  return result;
}
```

I call the function with `nibbleToInt("0010");` and it returns `8663`

**EDIT:**

Here is the working program due to the below response:

```
int nibbleToInt(String val) {
  int result = 0;

  if(val.substring(3,4) == "1") { result += 1; }
  if(val.substring(2,3) == "1") { result += 2; }
  if(val.substring(1,2) == "1") { result += 4; }
  if(val.substring(0,1) == "1") { result += 8; }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize `result`.

Comment: you are never initialzing result.  Thus the value will continue to increment each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you initialize `result` you might see different results.  :)  Otherwise (I believe) it will take the existing value in memory each time.